# ImageView can't be positioned in the right place in the Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-relativelayout

I want to make a shopping cart image, with a little indicator at the top-right corner to show how many products were selected/ordered. 
The thing is, I can't place it in the top right corner, only the left one (default) or center.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

         <ImageView
              android:id="@+id/shoppingCartIcon"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:src="@drawable/icon_cart" />

         <ImageView
              android:id="@+id/indicatorIcon"
              android:layout_width="10dp"
              android:layout_height="10dp"
              android:layout_gravity="top|right"
              android:src="#0066ff" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using FrameLayout you can give it with some padding & margin

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/shoppingCartIcon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_cart" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/indicatorIcon"
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="top|right"
            android:src="#0066ff" />

    </FrameLayout>
```

***UPDATE***

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/shoppingCartIcon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_cart" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/indicatorIcon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top|right"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:background="@drawable/circle_shape"
            android:text="5"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

    </FrameLayout>
```

You can create shape as per your wish

***res/drawable/circle_shape.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="#0066ff"></solid>

</shape>
```

Apart from this i would suggest you other third library which is very nice for displaying this type of badge or highlighted view

- https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-viewbadger
- https://github.com/mikepenz/Android-ActionItemBadge

Comment: and do you know how can I change the number text on the `indicatorIcon `(according to the orders) ? Do I have to use TextView on top? or just add text to the ImageView itself can work?

Answer (score 0):

you can add this code to your ImageView tag.

```
android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
```

It will make the ImageView go right marginLeft gives a blank depends on the size you want. You can change the size however you want.

Answer (score 0):

The parent is a `RelativeLayout` so try to use the properties :

```
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
```

on your `"@+id/indicatorIcon"`.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/shoppingCartIcon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/icon_cart" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/indicatorIcon"
    android:layout_width="10dp"
    android:layout_height="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="#0066ff" />

</RelativeLayout>
```